# caret::confusionMatrix internal matrix error chr length of dinnames that are not equal to array extent

Tags: r, matrix, r-caret, predict

**Problem**

caret::confusionMatrix. Code in R has new functions and includes Try/Catch, but on execution of R functions, no errors except internal to matrix.

For my calculation using iteration on accuracy, to calculate confusionMatrix sensitivity, specificity, accuracy, I can do that successful on a non-loop and get all measures. But when I use variables to build the confusionMatrix inside the function (compute_seq_accuracy.func) I have included an Try/Catch block; which when run, does not show an errors; but the function also DOES NOT create the confusionMatrix correctly. So I had to create a custom function to fix the levels error from the confusionMatrix, This function is called: compute_confusion_table.func() which takes the y response variable and  the  predict variable matrix and fixes missing row names and col names and returns a valid contingency table (e.g, return(ccm.func.confusion_table)

The main driver program function (e.g, compute_seq_accuracy.func) takes the sequence values (01...0.9) and calls the function compute_consusion_table.func() to return a valid contingency table. BUT this function does not work correctly to calculate the confusionMatrix, There is no Try/Catch error; but inside the matrix within the function I can see that there is an internal error on the "chr length of  dinnames that are not equal to array extent". This error is visible through str() on the variable embedded inside the function for debugging. I have a debugging statement str() inside compute_matrix.func() function which clearly shows the internal error on "chr length of  dinnames that are not equal to array extent"

**Code Attempt**

```
loans_predict <- predict(full, newdata=loans_train_data, type="response", na.action=na.pass)

compute_seq_accuracy.func <- function(value) {
        tryCatch({
                csa.func.p <- factor(ifelse(loans_predict < value, "Good", "Bad"))
                csa.func.confusion_table <- compute_confusion_table.func(loans_train_data$statusRank, csa.func.p)
                tryCatch({
                        csa.cmt <- compute_matrix.func(csa.func.p, csa.func.confusion_table)
        str(csa.cmt)
                },
                error = function(e) return(e)
                )
                return(csa.cmt$overall['Accuracy'])
        },
        error = function(e) return(e)
        )
}

compute_matrix.func <- function(p, t) {
        tryCatch({
                cm.func.confusion_matrix <- caret::confusionMatrix(p, t, positive="1", alpha=0.05)
        str(cm.func.confusion_matrix)
                return(cm.func.confusion_matrix$overall['Accuracy'])
        },

        error = function(e) return(e)
        )
}

##
compute_confusion_table.func <- function(y, p) {
        tryCatch({
                ccm.func.confusion_table <- table(y, p)
                if(nrow(ccm.func.confusion_table)!=ncol(ccm.func.confusion_table)){
                        missings <- setdiff(colnames(ccm.func.confusion_table),rownames(ccm.func.confusion_table))
                        missing_mat <- mat.or.vec(nr = length(missings), nc = ncol(ccm.func.confusion_table))
                        ccm.func.confusion_table  <- as.table(rbind(as.matrix(ccm.func.confusion_table), missing_mat))
                        rownames(ccm.func.confusion_table) <- colnames(ccm.func.confusion_table)
                }
                return(ccm.func.confusion_table)
        },
        error = function(e) return(e)
        )
}

compute_for_values <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by=0.1)

csa_copmuted_accuracies <- sapply(compute_for_values, compute_seq_accuracy.func, simplify=FALSE) 

names(csa_computed_accuracies) <- compute_for_values

csa_computed_accuracies[which.max(as.numeric(csa_computed_accuracies))
```

**Additional Explanation**

R confusionMatrix for the accuracy range (0.1...0.9) but ran into trouble on internal error "chr length of dinnames that are not equal to array extent" Yet since I only ran the glm2() function, and the predict() function before the confusionMatrix, I never changed the column names nor issues any rbind() that would have change the column names / order, so I am at a loss on why I have this confusionMatrix function throwing an error when the predicted and actual parameters which do not have the same number of levels. So now I understand that the functions in caret package go to great lengths to ensure predictions always have the same levels as the original classes. That is the purpose for the compute_confusion_table.func function. So in addition, also, my other question is where (?), or when (?) did this data (predicted and actual) ultimately get the levels out of sync for incorrect out of sync levels?

**Data Sample**

loans_predict

```
> dput(loans_predict[1:20])
c(`11413` = 0.803325118108046, `2561` = NA, `25337` = 0.853849488971217, 
`1643` = 0.793893769102712, `14264` = 0.714721872072079, `24191` = 0.778606178072608, 
`33989` = 0.890633845537385, `28193` = 0.798171905376348, `21129` = 0.898502735539081, 
`7895` = 0.881058550796637, `29007` = 0.760753392722403, `26622` = 0.662375927088179, 
`3065` = 0.925597132852884, `11423` = 0.763460597845282, `3953` = 0.921791256610175, 
`5789` = 0.745157387706153, `30150` = 0.587949357489077, `6070` = 0.915098837460939, 
`1486` = 0.680767185297498, `13195` = 0.76299062675687)
>
```

loans_train_data

```
> dput(loans_train_data[1:20,])
structure(list(loan_id = c(551879L, 442449L, 187882L, 619315L, 
453195L, 513713L, 647765L, 296L, 571832L, 128305L, 358197L, 26517L, 
12653L, 374086L, 305620L, 197445L, 307835L, 331697L, 550455L, 
301842L), amount = c(8400L, 15000L, 15600L, 12000L, 9975L, 21000L, 
20000L, 7500L, 21000L, 16000L, 4800L, 25000L, 7500L, 15600L, 
3000L, 3900L, 20125L, 25000L, 11975L, 11825L), term = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("36", "60"), class = "factor"), rate = c(0.12, 
0.1, 0.12, 0.15, 0.16, 0.12, 0.09, 0.12, 0.11, 0.09, 0.13, 0.2, 
0.07, 0.17, 0.07, 0.19, 0.19, 0.08, 0.15, 0.1), payment = c(280.17, 
483.94, 518.07, 415.93, 348.78, 700.42, 640.57, 250.51, 687.42, 
510.07, 161.02, 928.97, 233.27, 556.11, 92.49, 143.89, 521.95, 
785.49, 282.69, 251.19), grade = structure(c(5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L
), .Label = c("-1", "10", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100"), class = "factor"), 
    employment = c("store manager", "", "IT Director", "IT Specialist", 
    "Patient Serbice Rep", "Manager", "Service Technician", "E-6", 
    "Pharmacist/Pharmacy Supervisor", "Direct Sales Supervisor", 
    "Documement Associate", "Project Manager - Training", "Senior Accountant", 
    "Executive Assistant", "Chef", "Retail Sales, Production Assistant", 
    "Legislative Auditor", "System Specialist", "Lab Tech", "Store Manager"
    ), length = c(10, NA, 3, 6, 6, 4, 10, 8, 6, 3, 6, 10, 3, 
    1, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 4), home = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L), .Label = c("MORTGAGE", "OWN", "RENT"), class = "factor"), 
    income = c(49600, 62255, 131000, 80000, 60000, 116000, 80000, 
    75132, 115000, 68000, 28000, 70000, 70000, 79000, 50000, 
    36000, 58000, 78900, 30000, 82000), verified = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Not Verified", "Source Verified", 
    "Verified"), class = "factor"), status = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Charged Off", "Default", "Fully Paid"
    ), class = "factor"), reason = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L), .Label = c("car", "credit_card", "debt_consolidation", 
    "home_improvement", "house", "major_purchase", "medical", 
    "moving", "other", "renewable_energy", "small_business", 
    "vacation", "wedding"), class = "factor"), state = structure(c(46L, 
    21L, 30L, 2L, 5L, 11L, 14L, 5L, 37L, 42L, 42L, 44L, 33L, 
    8L, 19L, 11L, 41L, 14L, 3L, 33L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", 
    "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", 
    "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", 
    "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", 
    "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", 
    "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), 
    debt_inc_rat = c(20.42, 14.9, 12.83, 20.07, 26.18, 15.26, 
    25.59, 6.01, 21.07, 10.94, 31.2, 13.12, 9.33, 1.2, 11.74, 
    27.7, 26.65, 19.24, 23.4, 21.84), delinq2yr = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), inq6mth = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), open_acc = c(10L, 
    13L, 9L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 6L, 18L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 
    16L, 16L, 7L, 26L, 4L, 19L), pub_rec = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), revol_ratio = c(0.22, 0.53, 0.62, 0.61, 0.58, 0.78, 
    0.66, 0.04, 0.85, 0.46, 0.46, 0.92, 0.59, 0.32, 0.21, 0.72, 
    0.85, 0.57, 0.64, 0.23), total_acc = c(26L, 17L, 29L, 35L, 
    20L, 8L, 18L, 8L, 40L, 16L, 14L, 28L, 26L, 11L, 26L, 36L, 
    24L, 41L, 15L, 36L), total_paid = c(10004.43161, 17053.23761, 
    17788.62, 8909.41, 2424.16, 22618.02, 23069.03794, 8820.741039, 
    20586.97, 18349.10828, 1213.64, 18590.71, 8394.285943, 16982.69, 
    3293.165743, 5093.61, 21429.4, 25922.82, 12875.89999, 12959.12
    ), total_bal = c(175097L, 25184L, 39845L, 276866L, 44292L, 
    66042L, 233534L, 7059L, 219927L, 114621L, 29741L, 335392L, 
    46661L, 114486L, 22527L, 40819L, 176379L, 238772L, 57456L, 
    71201L), total_rev_lim = c(19000L, 47100L, 25700L, 13040L, 
    17900L, 65500L, 72100L, 39800L, 64900L, 20100L, 28200L, 20700L, 
    7100L, 9600L, 55700L, 7200L, 27000L, 8300L, 7200L, 34300L
    ), acc_open24 = c(4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L), avg_bal = c(17510L, 
    1937L, 4427L, 21297L, 4027L, 16511L, 23353L, 1177L, 12937L, 
    10420L, 4249L, 47913L, 3589L, 22897L, 1408L, 2721L, 25197L, 
    9184L, 14364L, 4188L), bc_open = c(6690L, 19007L, 7940L, 
    2267L, 5888L, 7758L, 16881L, 35401L, 782L, 5818L, 12515L, 
    0L, 2942L, 0L, 35319L, 1834L, 360L, 2316L, 2600L, 23337L), 
    bc_ratio = c(14.2, 56.6, 66.5, 77, 33.8, 80.8, 57.9, 3.8, 
    98.4, 49.4, 49.3, 102.2, 58.6, 103.7, 20.5, 67.8, 98.5, 66.9, 
    63.9, 25), total_lim = c(207427L, 47352L, 57626L, 292092L, 
    69796L, 88066L, 298525L, 57181L, 259850L, 131377L, 54172L, 
    361379L, 53648L, 124005L, 69108L, 69822L, 201136L, 253377L, 
    73564L, 114318L), total_rev_bal = c(31782L, 25184L, 39845L, 
    44598L, 44292L, 66042L, 84958L, 7059L, 134381L, 23389L, 29741L, 
    25022L, 46661L, 3088L, 22527L, 23481L, 81434L, 94468L, 33134L, 
    71201L), total_bc_lim = c(7800L, 43800L, 23700L, 6800L, 8900L, 
    40500L, 40100L, 36800L, 48200L, 11500L, 24700L, 16800L, 7100L, 
    2000L, 44400L, 5700L, 23400L, 7000L, 7200L, 31100L), total_il_lim = c(38991L, 
    0L, 31926L, 44052L, 51896L, 22566L, 71125L, 17381L, 104950L, 
    14140L, 25972L, 10000L, 46548L, 0L, 13408L, 28244L, 59542L, 
    99477L, 32892L, 80018L), statusRank = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(11413L, 
2561L, 25337L, 1643L, 14264L, 24191L, 33989L, 28193L, 21129L, 
7895L, 29007L, 26622L, 3065L, 11423L, 3953L, 5789L, 30150L, 6070L, 
1486L, 13195L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

**Data Trace from Debug str()**

When the R code is run, the following str(csa.cmt) is issued from prior statement:

```
csa.cmt <- compute_matrix.func(csa.func.p, csa.func.confusion_table)
```

However, the handling of the difference of 'same levels' was coded to be handled and corrected inside the called / invoked the function 'compute_confusion_table.func'

```
> csa_computed_accuracies <- sapply(compute_for_values, compute_seq_accuracy.func, simplify = FALSE)
List of 2
 $ message: chr "`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
 $ call   : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
List of 2
 $ message: chr "`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
 $ call   : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
List of 2
 $ message: chr "`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
 $ call   : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
List of 2
 $ message: chr "`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
 $ call   : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
List of 2
 $ message: chr "`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
 $ call   : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
List of 2
 $ message: chr "`data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
 $ call   : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
>
```

Comment: Hi sorry i read your question twice and can you help me on what would be the main question? Is it to understand why compute_seq_accuracy.func throws an error?

Comment: If that is the case, can you provide an example dataset so that this is reproducible. Quite a bit of stuff in these functions are specific to your dataset